# Getting illegal argument exception in mediabuttonreceiver

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-mediasession

I am trying to play song in my service and I am  able to play it successfully for lollipop and above device .I saw some tutorial and it show that using the classname method we can do it for pre lollipop device this is what i am getting as error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service beatbox.neelay.beatbox.MediaService@41e92b60 with Intent { cmp=beatbox.neelay.beatbox/.MediaService }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MediaButtonReceiver component may not be null.
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:133)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MediaButtonReceiver component may not be null.
                                                                        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplBase.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:1507)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:278)
                                                                        at beatbox.neelay.beatbox.MediaService.initMediaSession(MediaService.java:660)
                                                                        at beatbox.neelay.beatbox.MediaService.onStartCommand(MediaService.java:172)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:133) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

07

this is how i am calling the service 
in main activity binding part

```
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        MediaService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaService.LocalBinder) service;
        MainActivity.this.player = binder.getService();
        serviceBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};
```

this is how i am calling the service

```
Intent playerIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaService.class);
        playerIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(playerIntent);
        bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

this is my mediasession method where i am getting the error

```
 private void initMediaSession() throws RemoteException {
    if (mediaSessionManager != null)  //mediaSessionManager exists

    mediaSessionManager  = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MediaButtonReceiver.class);

    // Create a new MediaSession
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "Tag", mediaSessionManager, null);
    //Get MediaSessions transport controls
    transportControls = mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
    //set MediaSession -> ready to receive media commands
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    //indicate that the MediaSession handles transport control commands
    // through its MediaSessionCompat.Callback.
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonIntent.setClass(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
    mediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(pendingIntent);
```

the app is running properly for android M but it is showing this error for android jellybean

Comment: Why are you calling both startService & bindService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare a `MediaButtonReceiver` in you manifest.xml file that will delegate all the media button key to the MediaSession service

```
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

More here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html

and here

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons.html